# Building the filter built-in function with Racket

Tags: filter, functional-programming, lisp, racket, sicp

I am trying to build filter (a built-in function) using Racket just as a matter of practice.

I created the following code:

```
(define (filter lista-1 check-function)
 (define (fil-iter lista-1 check-function lista-2)
  (cond ((null? lista-1) lista-2)
        ((check-function (car lista-1)) (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) check-function (append lista-2 (list (car lista-1)))))
        (else (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) check-function lista-2))))
   (trace fil-iter)
   (fil-iter lista-1 check-function '()))
```

I made a few tests with "odd?", "even?" and "number?" as the "check-function".

All of the outputs were correct. But I might be not seeing something... My intuition says that there is something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is correct, only it has a complexity of *n*² while it could have a complexity of *n*.

The reason is that you use `append` instead of `cons` to build the result, and `append` has a cost proportional to the length of the list, while `cons` has a constant cost. So, if you want a function with linear complexity you should write something like:

```
(define (filter lista-1 check-function)
 (define (fil-iter lista-1 check-function lista-2)
  (cond ((null? lista-1) (reverse lista-2))
        ((check-function (car lista-1))
         (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) check-function (cons (car lista-1) lista-2)))
        (else (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) check-function lista-2))))
   (fil-iter lista-1 check-function '()))
```

Note that at the end the result must be reversed, but this does not change the complexity of the function since `reverse` has a linear complexity with the size of the list and is executed only once, at the end of the function.

You can also simplify the function noting that the parameter `check-function` is not modified at each invocation of the helper `fil-iter`, so it could be omitted inside it:

```
(define (filter lista-1 check-function)
 (define (fil-iter lista-1 lista-2)
  (cond ((null? lista-1) (reverse lista-2))
        ((check-function (car lista-1))
         (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) (cons (car lista-1) lista-2)))
        (else (fil-iter (cdr lista-1) lista-2))))
   (fil-iter lista-1 '()))
```

Comment: you are my professor! Thanks, another great explanation!

Comment: I was avoiding the reverse... Is there another way to use cons instead of append and not using reverse?

Comment: Then you can use the techniques shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40096809/2382734) to one of your question. Another way is by using side-effects, with mutable lists, but this is not typical in functional programming. I really do not understand way you don't want to use `reverse`: when using an accumulator in a tail-recursive function the use of `reverse` is really idiomatic in Scheme and other lisp languages.

Comment: Thanks! I am just a beginner. I did not know this was an idiomatic behavior.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `for/list` with `#:when` clause to create a filter function:

```
(define (myfilter proc lst)
  (for/list ((item lst)
             #:when (proc item))
    item))

(myfilter even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
; => '(2 4 6)
```