# Building map with Racket

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, racket, sicp

I was building the map function as a matter of practice.

I came up with the following code:

```
#lang racket

(define (map procedure items)
  (if (null? items)
      empty
      (cons (procedure (car items)) (map procedure (cdr items)))))
```

I tried this and it worked fine:

```
(map add1 '(1 2 3))

>> '(2 3 4)
```

Then I tried this and it also worked fine:

```
(define (scale-by-3 item)
  (* 3 item))

(map scale-by-3 '(1 2 3))

>> '(3 6 9)
```

After that, I decided to generalize the scale procedure:

```
(define (scale-by-factor factor item)
  (* factor item))
```

This scale-by-factor function works:

```
(scale-by-factor 3 4)

>> 12
```

But when I tried using it with the map:

```
(map (scale-by-factor 2 item) '(1 2 3))
```

I got the following error:

```
item: unbound identifier in module in: item
```

How do I solve this? Is there a way of solving it without lambda?

Comment: Answers will be different for Racket and Lisp. A Lisp programmer might write an [anaphoric macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because `item` doesn't exist at the time you call it - it's passed by `map` as a parameter when traversing the list. To solve the problem, do something like this:

```
(map (lambda (item) (scale-by-factor 2 item))
     '(1 2 3))
```

Or we can write a nicer alternative using [`curry`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29), which creates a `lambda` that expects the missing `item` parameter:

```
(map (curry scale-by-factor 2)
     '(1 2 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `item` is indeed not bound. You haven't define it anywhere.

What you want is a partial application of `scale-by-factor`. This function takes two argument and evaluates to a result. But if you partially apply it on only one argument, it will evaluate to a function that takes the other argument and evaluates to the final result.

You can achieve this using `curry` in Racket, as seen [here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29).

```
(define (map procedure items)
  (if (null? items)
    empty
    (cons (procedure (car items)) (map procedure (cdr items)))))

(define (scale-by-factor factor item)
  (* factor item))

(map (curry scale-by-factor 5) '(1 2 3))
```

It is called `curry` because of [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)

Comment: Exactly. It's just when I wrote it, your answer haven't rendered on the website yet.

Answer (score 0):

Great solutions here. I'll offer some alternatives so you can see more ways of doing the same thing

You can define the `scale-by-factor` function in curried form

```
(define ((scale-by-factor x) y)
  (* x y))

; note it needs two applications to get the computed result now
((scale-by-factor 3) 4)
; => 12
```

You can define a tail-recursive map using the [CPS technique I showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40096809/633183) on one of your other questions

```
(define (map f xs)
  (let iter ([xs xs] [k identity])
    (if (empty? xs)
        (k empty)
        (let ([v (f (car xs))])
          (iter (cdr xs) (λ (rest) (k (cons v rest))))))))

(map (scale-by-factor 2) '(1 2 3))
; => '(2 4 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Racket `for/list` can be used to create map function:

```
(define (mymap proc lst)
  (for/list ((item lst))
    (proc item)))

(mymap add1 '(1 2 3))
; =>'(2 3 4)
```